# Unable to get a peer to join a channel using Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've been trying to follow the instructions here to create a new channel (based on an existing channel) and have an existing peer join that channel. https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-create.html

The error I'm encountering is on `newChannel.joinChannel(j_request)`. The raises `[JoinChain][composerchannel2]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]]`

But I don't know how to make sure the current user is an admin.

My network is based on the basic-network in the fabric samples directory. I enrol an admin using the script from the fabcar example. See below. And I'm then trying to make sure the admin user is the current user submitting the join channel request like this:

```
const setAdminAsUser = async () => {
  try {
    const admin = await fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true)
    return fabric_client.setUserContext(admin, true)
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error setting admin as user', error)
  }
}
```

Then my function to invite peers to the channel looks like this (though note there is only one organisation and one peer):

```
const invitePeerToChannel = async () => {
  console.log('invite peer to channel')

  var newChannel = fabric_client.newChannel('composerchannel2');
  var orderer  = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpc://localhost:7050');
  var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:7051');

  newChannel.addOrderer(orderer);
  newChannel.addPeer(peer);

  tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID(true);
  let g_request = {
    txId: tx_id
  };

  // get the genesis block from the orderer
  newChannel.getGenesisBlock(g_request).then((block) =>{
    genesis_block = block;
    tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID(true);
    let j_request = {
      targets: ['localhost:7051'],
      block: genesis_block,
      txId: tx_id
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(j_request))

    // send genesis block to the peer
    return newChannel.joinChannel(j_request);
  }).then((results) =>{
    if(results && results.response && results.response.status == 200) {
      console.log('Joined correctly')
    } else {
      console.log('Failed', results)
    }
  });
}
```

Function for enrolling the admin, based on the fabcar example:

```
const enrollAdmin = () => {
  // create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
  return Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path}).then((state_store) => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
    var tlsOptions = {
      trustedRoots: [],
      verify: false
    };
    // be sure to change the http to https when the CA is running TLS enabled
    fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:7054', tlsOptions , 'ca.org1.example.com', crypto_suite);
    // first check to see if the admin is already enrolled
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);
  }).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
      console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
      admin_user = user_from_store;
      return null;
    } else {
      // need to enroll it with CA server
      return fabric_ca_client.enroll({
        enrollmentID: 'admin',
        enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw'
      }).then((enrollment) => {
        console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"');
        return fabric_client.createUser(
            {username: 'admin',
              mspid: 'Org1MSP',
              cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
            });
      }).then((user) => {
        admin_user = user;
        return fabric_client.setUserContext(admin_user);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to enroll and persist admin. Error: ' + err.stack ? err.stack : err);
        throw new Error('Failed to enroll admin');
      });
    }
  }).then(() => {
      console.log('Assigned the admin user to the fabric client ::' + admin_user.toString());
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.error('Failed to enroll admin: ' + err);
  });
}
```

Hitting a brick wall with the tutorial docs so any help would be brilliant!

EDIT:

Here is how I'm currently generating the config update then signing it. This is based on the SDK tutorial.

```
// This takes a config file that includes the organisations that will be added to the channel
const encodeChannelConfig = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('encoding channel config')

    var config_json = fs.readFileSync("./newChannel.json");
    config_json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(config_json))

    superagent.post('http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/encode/common.ConfigUpdate',
      config_json)
      .buffer()
      .end((err, res) => {
        if(err) {
          return;
        }
        resolve(res.body);
      });
  })
}

const signChannelConfig = (encodedChannelConfig) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('signing channel config')

    var signature = fabric_client.signChannelConfig(encodedChannelConfig);
    signatures.push(signature);
    resolve(signatures);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a setAdminSigningIdentity on your fabric_client if you haven't already.

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html#setAdminSigningIdentity

This will allow the admin credentials to be used when you do the newTransactionID with the true option.

Note this admin is not the same as the admin user from the CA and the private key and cert are generated by cryptogen and are likely in a directory similar to

crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/users/Admin@org1/msp/keystore

crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/users/Admin@org1/msp/signcerts

Comment: Thanks Eric. setAdminSigningIdentity overcame the error I was getting, I think. But the `newChannel.joinChannel(j_request)` is still failing, now with this error: `[ { Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP]`. 
It doesn't look right that that channel array is empty, but I don't really know what to expect.

Comment: Did you do a client.createChannel(request) at some point before doing the joinChannel? The admin credentials will be needed for this step as well.

Comment: Yes, but when I do the setAdminSigningIdentity prior to the createChannel the submission response looks like this: `{ status: 'FORBIDDEN',
  info: 'Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied' }`

Comment: Check the signatures that you include in the createChannel request.  I was able to recreate the same error message by not including any signatures in the request object.

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated the question to show how I'm generating the config update and signing it. Before those steps I'm calling setAdminSigningIdentity, so I believe the config should be signed by the organisation admin. Is there some other way to check the signatures, do you know?

Comment: May be relevant that I've noticed changing `AdminPrincipal: Role.MEMBER` to `AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN` in configtx.yaml (then regenerating the genesis block, tearing down the network and then rerunning the fabric start script) results in a similar error: `Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining`

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any problems with your encodeChannelConfig and signChannelConfig functions.  I gave them a try and both worked for me.  Also I'm using Role.ADMIN.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric

Comment: Hey guys, the thing is I have fabric-ca admin user. then I use this admin to create channel. It worked like a charm. but when I want to join the channel, this admin doesn't work anymore. so as Eric said, I should use cryptogen generated admin. WHy did it let me to create channel with fabric-ca admin and not let me to join the channel with this admin?

Comment: I don't have an explanation for what you are seeing.  The clients I use to create the channel have the admin signing identities set, and it looks like the client signChannelConfig call automatically uses the admin if it is available.